# pgfplots 3D surface broke

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'm a newcomer to LaTeX and pgfplots. And now I found a problem while I was using `\addplot3`. It seems that the image behaved abnormally on perspective.This is the image generated.
[image]

For reference I changed to `view={20}{0}`, and it became the image below.
[image]

Could anyone tell me how to deal with it, please? I don't know how to make the first image right.
My tex code is

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, xunicode, xltxtra, pgfplots}  
\setmainfont{Hiragino Sans GB}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\title{Title}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
small,
view={20}{30}
] \addplot3[surf,mesh/cols=50,domain=-2:2,domain y=-1.3:1.3]
            table {2.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{a small example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I say print 1000 copies and sell it as an "M.C. Escher" original print.  Good first question!

Comment: Try putting `z buffer=sort` in your `\addplot3 [...]` options.

Comment: Did you try `z buffer= sort`?

Comment: Could you provide your data file? When plotting just the function `{x*exp(-x*x-y*y)}`, I could not reproduce the behavior...

Comment: @Jake Thanks a lot! It works after I add `z buffer=sort`.

Comment: Hi, am author of `pgfplots`. Could you provide the data file `2.dat`? `pgfplots` is supposed to draw plots like that correctly out of the box and I will see what I can do. If the file is too long (looks like 50x50), you can send it by mail (my address is in on top of the pgfplots manual).

Comment: ... you can also try to reduce the number of samples and insert the data file into your question, of course. The issue should be present with less data points as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use the option `z buffer = sort` to correct the sorting in the data file. If you plot the function directly in pgfplots, the problem does not exist....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
small,
view={20}{20}
] 
\addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2,samples=50]
           {x*exp(-x*x-y*y)} ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{a small example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]